# Java how can I pass varargs to another function like Paths.get()

Tags: java, arguments, variadic-functions

I'm trying to pass varargs to `Paths.get()`

From my understanding, varargs essentially interpreted as an array. But `get()` method expects individual String's not one String array.

How can I pass the varargs through to the method?

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public static Path getLogFilePath(String... stringArgs) {
    int sLen = stringArgs.length;

    Path path = Paths.get(stringArgs); // Cannot resolve method 'get(java.lang.String[])'
    return path;
}
```

Comment: is `Paths` class written by you?

Comment: `Paths.get(stringArgs[0], theRemainingStrings);` and check that `stringArgs` contains one or more elements beforehand.

Comment: You can pass as long as other one accepts it. In this case you might want to just pass `stringArgs[0]` ?

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare Added imports I used.

Comment: Your premise is flawed : the method is `Paths.get(String path, String... others)`. You CAN pass a `String[]` in a varargs argument

Comment: @JeremyGrand Are you saying the code above should work? Why does my IDE spit out an error?

Comment: @tyleax because it's not supposed to be `Paths.get(myArray)`, it's `Paths.get(alwaysOneString, myPotentiallyEmptyArray)` . `Paths::get` always had 2 arguments, a `String` AND a `String[]`.

Comment: Whats up with my down vote? Is this not a valid question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another take on this would be to mimic the `Paths.get()` prototype :

```
public static Path getLogFilePath(String first, String... others) {
    if( first == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Always a first String !!!");
    }

    Path path = Paths.get(first, others); // Compiles !
    return path;
}
```

NOTE : `Paths.get` uses two arguments on purpose to explicitely tell users that at least one String is needed. Implementing a method above it that allows to pass an empty array is, in my opinion, just a `RuntimeException` in waiting.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to explicitly handle separating the first argument:

```
Path path = Paths.get(stringArgs[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(stringArgs, 1, sLen);
```

Comment: There is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` hidden in your code